# Determining the unmanaged memory leak in Azure Web Role (Windows Azure Accelerator)

Tags: azure, memory-leaks, windbg, azure-web-roles

We are using the now deprecated [Windows Azure Accelerator](http://ntotten.com/2011/07/05/windows-azure-accelerator-for-web-roles/) to deploy multiple applications to a Windows Azure web role. We have noticed a massive memory leak in the **WAIISHost.exe** process - it is currently consuming 2.5GB of RAM (on a Large Azure instance). One week ago, it was at 1.5GB, so it's safe to say it leaks a gig a week.

We've looked at the memory dump and it appears that the leak is unmanaged - using SOS in WinDBG revealed no more than 50MB of managed heap.

We've used the [heap_stat.py](https://github.com/goldshtn/windbg-extensions/blob/master/heap_stat.py) WinDBG extension and it revealed that most of the allocated objects come from nativerd dll (which I believe is an internal infrastructure library). Here is what !py heap_stat.py -stat revealed:

> Statistics:
>
> ```
>                                      Type name         Count  Size
>                      nativerd!SCHEMA_ATTRIBUTE       8127384  Unknown
>                       nativerd!ATTRIBUTE_VALUE       8127037  Unknown
>                        nativerd!SCHEMA_ELEMENT       2032263  Unknown
>                        nativerd!CONFIG_ELEMENT       1112616  Unknown
>                       nativerd!NAMED_ENTRY_KEY         99967  Unknown
>                       nativerd!DICTIONARY_LIST         54152  Unknown
>                       nativerd!DUPLICATE_TABLE         11654  Unknown
> ```

Running !heap -p -a on any of those objects did not reveal much additional information:

> 0:000> !heap -p -a 000000002c1591e0
>
> ```
> address 000000002c1591e0 found in
> _HEAP @ 8d0000
>           HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags            UserPtr UserSize - state
>     000000002c1591e0 0014 0000  [00]   000000002c1591f0    00130 - (busy)
>       nativerd!SCHEMA_ELEMENT::`vftable'
> ```

At this point, we are wondering what could the next steps investigating the memleak be. Is there any other useful information that can be extracted from the memory dump, or should we resort to other means such as inspecting the code and trying to run locally with a profiler?

**Update:** Our VMs are running Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1. We are using Azure SDK 1.7. Finally, the version of nativerd.dll is 7.5.7601.17855

Comment: Can you find out the version of nativerd? `lm vm nativerd`

Comment: Maybe KB2708071 is relevant: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2708071 It may be caused by caching. NativeReader has been updated to 7.0.6002.22847 with that hotfix.

Comment: Our VM is running Windows Server 2008 R2 so it does not look like that hotfix is applicable (nativerd.dll is 7.5.7601.17855)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've taken the deprecated Windows Azure Accelerator for Web Roles and giving it much needed love. It's been upgraded to fix the problem you have indicated here as well as upgrade to Windows Server 2012 (currently it's against 1.8 SDK, but if you know what you are doing it should work fine with 2.X).

You can check it out here: https://github.com/MRCollective/AzureWebFarm

The immediate fix for the problem you are experiencing is shown in this commit: https://github.com/MRCollective/AzureWebFarm/commit/467516c77fa23b23fa94f98deb38679cfd08663a, alternatively, if you upgrade to Windows Server 2012 then the problem no longer exists.

Another option that we recently produced is here: https://github.com/MRCollective/AzureWebFarm.OctopusDeploy

Comment: Pretty cool - good to see that Windows Azure Accelerator has been given a second life! As far as my issue is concerned, my understanding is that it's a Win2k8 R2 bug, mitigated by KB2618982. We will try to deploy it to see if it fixes the leak.